# solr dataimport not working for URLdatasource

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

This is my data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="a" type="URLDataSource"  encoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="5000" readTimeout="10000"/>
<document name="products">
                     <entity name="images" dataSource="a"       
                    url="file:///abc/1299.xml"
                    processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                    forEach="/imagesList/image"
                    >
                            <field column="id"  xpath="/imageList/image/productId" />
                            <field column="image_array"  xpath="/imageList/image/imageUrlString" />
                    </entity>


</document>
</dataConfig>
```

This is the schema.xml

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="image_array" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multivalued="true"/>
```

But when I try to deltaimport, none of the documents get added.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off, your XPath says `imageList` and your XML says `imagesList` ...